# Pygame: Unable to open .mp3 file

Tags: python, audio, pygame

So... Whenever I try to run this block of code:

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Memes.')

meme = pygame.mixer.Sound('JUST DO IT.mp3')
meme.play()
time.sleep(2)
meme.stop()

while True: # Main Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slay-Slay\Desktop\Python\Python Code\play soun.py", line 9, in <module>
    meme = pygame.mixer.Sound('JUST DO IT.mp3')
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'JUST DO IT.mp3'
```

Both the code and the sound are in the same exact folder, before you ask. I don't know what the problem could be... I thought pygame supported .mp3?

EDIT: I just tried it with the pygame.mixer.music.load() function... And that didn't work either. It instead gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Slay-Slay\Desktop\Python\Python Code\play soun.py", line 9, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load('JUST DO IT.mp3')
pygame.error: Couldn't read from 'JUST DO IT.mp3'
```

I also tried different formats, such as WAV or OGG. Neither worked. I tried all 3 formats on the 2 different functions. All returned the same errors. "Couldn't read from" for music.load, and "Unable to open file" for Sound.

Comment: My son had `pygame.mixer.Sound("explosion.mp3")` working on the game he wrote on his ChromeBook for school. I ported his game to my Windows 10, machine, using a fresh install of Python 3.10 and pygame 2.1.2, and it does not work.  And we tried `music` too and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 8):

There's another mixer method, `music`, that you should probably be using - `music` supports mp3, but `sound` doesn't. Try this.

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('JUST DO IT.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(2)
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

^that's a pretty dank meme by the way

Comment: I have the dankest memes around m8

Also... That didn't work. Gave me a similiar error. Edited the post with the new error.

Answer (score 3):

So pygame only allows for files that are either OGG or a compressed WAV file to be played using Sound. However you can use music instead of sound to play mp3 files. Plus next time you can look up the info on the PyGame documentation here. https://www.pygame.org/docs/

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Memes.')


pygame.mixer.music.load("foo.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(2)
pygame.mixer.music.stop()

while True: # Main Loop

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

just replace the foo.mp3 with your file

Comment: For some odd reason... It still doesn't work with OGG or WAV files... I just tried. Gives me the same exact error.

Comment: i will post your code modified with music, worked for me

Comment: Yeah... Didn't work. Same thing as I put into my post.

Comment: Honestly it could just be an issue with the file you are trying to load could have some issues, try loading up other files to see if it works

Comment: Welp. Just tried running it in IDLE. Apparently the IDE I was using was just glitching out and not saving the code properly. Well, thanks for the help anyways. :P

Answer (score 0):

MP3 file played correctly for me on both Windows 10 and Linux Fedora 31 (pygame 1.9.6, python 3), see below.

Your mileage may vary though as [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) states: "*Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead*".

```
import time
from pygame import mixer

def play(soundfile, duration_secs):
    """Play a soundfile for a configurable duration"""

    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(soundfile)
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(duration_secs)
    mixer.music.stop()
    mixer.quit()

# Play for 5 seconds
play('test.mp3', 5)
```

Comment: I had it working with mp3s on a Mac machine but not on a Linux Mint machine. Both running python 3 and pygame 2.0.0. Wavs work on both.