# Pygame - Music is not looping correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to loop music, but it doesn't loop correctly. For eg. If i write

```
pygame.mixer.music.play(5, 0.0)
```

Then it will only loop 3 times, if i pass 6 or 7, it loops 4 times, for 10 it loops 6 times, for 15 it loops 8 times and so on. I have tried different mp3 files but the result is the same. Although passing '-1' to loop infinitely works perfectly. What seems to be the problem here?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Blop!')

pygame.mixer.music.load('blop.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(15, 0.0)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Try  pygame.mixer.music(15)

Comment: @Wboy I think you mistyped your comment, as it gives a 'module not callable' error. Anyways, I tried pygame.mixer.music.play(15), but it is still only looping 8 times

Comment: No, I was referring to a comment from the docs https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html. Are you playing any files with long periods of silence?

Comment: @Wboy No, I've tried a bunch of audio files, like sirens or thunderclap sounds, which do not contain any periods of silence, but the result is the same.

Comment: Could you try not playing an mp3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668981/pygame-unable-to-open-mp3-file

Comment: @Wboy Yeah, I just converted audio file from mp3 to wav and it worked. I guess python doesn't like mp3. Anyways, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed pygame and created an .ogg to debug your code.

It works fine on my computer. I.e. calling music.play(15) loops it 15 times.

I suspect that your input music file is incorrect, pygame only accepts proper .ogg files and not mp3s. Could you try a different file, converted with http://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg and see if it works?